# How to delete files from Dropbox with PHP api

Tags: php, api, dropbox

First of all, I can properly upload and download files from Dropbox with the PHP api.

This is how I upload files:

```
// Upload files
$file = fopen("default.png", "rb");
$size = filesize("default.png");

$client->uploadFile("/default.png", Dropbox\WriteMode::add(), $file, $size);
```

This is how I download files:

```
// Download Files

$client->getFile("/default.png", fopen("default.png", "wb"));
```

Is there a api call to delete files from within the folder your app created. For example, my app creates a folder called **Crave Crap**. Inside, that folder is an image. That user only has access to that image within the folder Crave Crap within their Dropbox account for a short amount of time.

**Is this possible?**

**EDIT - What API am I using?**
I'm not the best at answering this question. I have been following a video series [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWGOceoK3I3LrDL6x8mM0Ipb). I downloaded the api by using the terminal directly on composer.json.

**Composer.json**

```
{
  "require": {
    "dropbox/dropbox-sdk": "1.1.*"
  }
}
```

**Code in Terminal**

```
composer install
```

Comment: we need to check the client API if it supports the delete feature as well, please provide the code or link of the client API you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [Dropbox PHP Core SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/php). To delete a file or folder using that SDK, you can use the [`delete`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.Client.html#_delete) method.

Using it would look like:

```
$client->delete("/default.png");
```

Comment: Would you mind giving an example? Does it look like this:$client->getFile("/default.png", fopen("default.png", "delete"));

Comment: No, `delete` is the method, in place of `getFile`. I've added a sample.

Comment: Is it simple to "output Dropbox content on to your website"? Does it use the same Dropbox PHP core SDK api?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but in any case, it sounds like a different question, so you should post it separately.